Determine if a list contains two consecutive 3s
I am trying to write a function that returns True if an input list contains two consecutive 3s somewhere. I wrote the following code, but I'm not sure whether it is correct:
def has_33(my_list):
    i=0
    for j in my_list:
        if i==j:
            return True
        else:
            i=j
    return False

My online instructor gave another solution using indexing ([]):
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return True  
    
    return False

Will my solution work? What about the online instructor's?

It is not correct.  has_33([1,1]) -> True

How can you even imagine that your code might be correct, when you never actually compare anything to the number 3?

"Will my solution work?". You'll find out when you test it. Testing is all part of the software development process

Your solution has a few issues and this is how I would update your code for clarity.
Hope this helps.
def has_33(my_list):
    i = None  
    for j in my_list:
        if i == 3 and j == 3:
            return True
        i = j
    return False

Pythonic way to write this:
def has_33(my_list):
    return any(x == 3 and y == 3 for x, y in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]))

References:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any


return (3, 3) in zip(my_list, my_list[1:])

Your online instructor's code will work. Your code won't; it'll only look for duplicate numbers without checking whether they're both 3.
I personally wouldn't use either, though. I'd opt for the itertools.pairwise function, which iterates over each pair of consecutive values in an iterable. Then, you can directly compare each pair to the tuple (3, 3). Here's an iterative version for readability:
import itertools

def has_33(my_list):
    for pair in itertools.pairwise(my_list):
        if pair == (3, 3):
            return True
    return False

Of course, the better solution is just to use in (kudos to @sureshvv for pointing this one out):
def has_33(my_list):
    return (3, 3) in itertools.pairwise(my_list)

